# DataStage Error: The OCI function OraOCIEnvNIsCreate:OCI_UTF16ID returned status -1

Tags: datastage

I am trying to preform a simple connection test in DataStage 8.7.

I have an Oracle_Connector inside a Parallel job.

I know the credentials are good as I can connect with them using something like SQL Developer.

However I am seeing the following error when I try the 'Test' button on the Properties tab.

(I also get the error when I change the "Use external authentication" from No to Yes; so that doesn't seem to be the issue.)

[image: DataStage error screenshot]

Any ideas as to what could be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem in Oracle client environment on DataStage server.

1) Check correctness of environment variable used by Oracle

NLS_LANG, ORACLE_HOME, etc.

2) Check permission for the datastage client user (dsadm or other user that use for log-in on DataStage Designer) that must have grant read and execute permission on all Oracle Client files and Oracle directory